# POST Request in Python w/ input string variables?

Tags: python, json, post, python-3.11

I'll try to be brief. I'm trying to create an API application that uses GET & POST requests to update our work order system. The gist of it is as such:

1. Display menu and get user selection
2. Depending on selection, get user input and do either a GET or POST request
3. Display menu again

Just so there's context, here's a snippet of the menu:

```
def mainmenu():
    print("Choose an option:")
    print("1. Add a new work order.")
    print("2. View a specific work order.")
    print("3. Update a specific work order.")
    print("4. Quit.")
```

I'm working on 1 right now:

```
def addReq():
    print("Please follow the prompts to add a new work order request.")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    subject = input("Enter the title of the new request:")
    description = input("Enter the issue/description for request in a few brief words:")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    print("Please wait a moment while your query is sent...")

    url = "https://MY_SERVER/api/v3/requests/"
    headers = {"authtoken": "MY_TOKEN"}

    adata = {
        "request": {
            "subject": f"{subject}",
            "description": f"{description}",
            "requester": {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "administrator"
            },
            "status": {
                "name": "Open"
            }
        }
    }

    input_data = json.dumps(adata)
    data = {'input_data': input_data}

    response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data,verify=False)
    print(response.json)
```

The request will go through, but garbage will come back, like the json response couldn't actually be parsed.

I have also tried formatting it like so, to no luck:

```
adata = {
        "request": {
            "subject": "{sub}",
            "description": "{desc}",
            "requester": {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "administrator"
            },
            "status": {
                "name": "Open"
            }
        }
    }.format(sub=subject, desc=description)
```

I get a different error with either method. Both have to do with using format incorrectly.

What is the proper way to take user input as a variable and pack it into JSON data for parsing in a POST request?

Thanks for your time and advice.

Edit: the first gave the error that I can't use format that many lines deep. The way around that I found was to do it as I did, but the response wasn't as expected. I don't believe I can hard code the values because they rely on user response and could change every time.

Comment: Please post the details of the errors.

Comment: Is it working for you with hard coded values?